Modelling a queueing system with equal processing speed across n workflows
Hey all need some help on a real world queuing system. Apologies if we are a little loose with some terminology.
Let a workflow $w_i$ consist of steps $s_k$. A workflow can have n steps, which are ordered, ie you need to go through step 1 before you can go to step 2
$w_1 = {\{s_1,s_2,s_3 ...\}}$ etc
A set of users can enter a workflow and progresses through each step in the workflow. Each time a user enters a step we create a job $J_i$, and that job to an ordered queue $Q$ and must be processed by our machine for a user to progress to the next step in the workflow. Each job has a priority, a positive integer, that defines when it gets processed in the Queue $Q$
here $J_i^2$ job $i$ has priority 2
Jobs are processed in a queue one at a time, and there is a constant processing speed of $q$ jobs per second. All jobs from all workflows get sent to the same queue.  If 2 jobs have the same priority they are processed in a (first in first out) FIFO manner. A job with priority 1, gets processed before a job of priority 2 and so on.
If the queue currently has 4 jobs like this:
$Q = {J_a^1, J_b^2, J_c^3, J_d^4}$
with priority 1,2,3,4 and another job $e$ is added with priority 1 the queue will next look like 1,1,2,3,4.
$Q = {J_a^1, J_e^1, J_b^2, J_c^3, J_d^4}$
Here's is visual representation:

Our system should be able to run multiple workflows at once, such that all the users in a single workflow are not processed before another workflow if both are active.
Ie we want perceived "parrelism". In addition we want to be as close as possible to equal speed of processing for each workflow, ie if there is only one wokflow active  it is being being processed at 10 jobs  per second, when workflow 2 is set to be active, then both should have jobs processed at 5 per second.
Workflows need not have the same number of steps.
Is there a formula that can define the priority for any job from any step in a workflow before it is put in the queue to satisfy our conditions. Our formula has access to the number of workflows at any time, and the number of steps in each workflow. This formula can only operate before a job is added to the queue it cannot change the priority after the fact.
How would the formula look different if

we know we can at run $max$ workflows at once,
if there were no limit to the number of workflows?
We wanted to prioritize finishing all the steps for a single user more than moving users equally through each step in a workflow

My initial thoughts for case 1) are for each workflow we use a function that selects the priority of a job from a gaussian like distribution such that for the first step, $E(priority) = max + 1$, $sd = 1$ then for the next step  $E(priority) = max + 2$, $sd = 1$  and so on.
Then for the next workflow the priority for jobs from the first step would be:
$E(priority) = max + 1 - (Active number of journeys)$, $sd = 2$, for the second $E(priority) = max + 1 - (Active number of journeys) + 1$, $sd = 2$
The increment to the $sd$ here doesn't have to be exactly 1 we can define it how we want.
I think this system would allow new workflows to add some jobs to the front of the queue but not sidestep all existing journeys, so that parralelism is achieved but I'm not sure how we would get equal speed though i imagine we could pick the $sd$ increments and expected priority decrements to make this work.
